# Is it possible to ignore seconds on date time filtering for RadGridView

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, telerik-grid, radgridview

I am using Telerik RadGridView with custom filter control.
Item source contains field with DateTime value. I need to filter by date ignoring seconds. 
One way is to remove seconds from items source, but it is not possible in my case.
Is there any other way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: you want this in asp.net ??

Comment: @JayeshGoyani app is WPF

Answer (score 1):

Like in your xaml if you are using basic filtering just add Filtermemberpath for DateTime value column

telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding mydate}" FilterMemberPath="date2"/>

Comment: I am using custom filtering not basic.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround could be add one more variable in your viewmodel and set it as filtermemberpath for the column

In your View model,

DateTime d = DateTime.Now; //or variable which is storing your datetime value

string sd = d.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");

Comment: Variable must be added to model, not view model. I already noticed that can't change source.